# deadlock using condition variable

Tags: multithreading, c++17

I have a question about condition_variable.

Having this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mut;
int value;

void sleep() {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
  // sleep forever
  cv.notify_one();
}

int main ()
{
  std::thread th (sleep);

  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mut);
  if(cv.wait_for(lck,std::chrono::seconds(1))==std::cv_status::timeout) {
    std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;
  }

  th.join();

  return 0;
}
```

How to resolve this deadlock
Why the wait_for blocks even after the 1 sec.

Is the mut necessary for the thread th ?

Thanks.

Comment: What does '// sleep forever' mean? Are you trying to say that the `cv.notify_one()` call will never happen? If that's so, then why not just remove it? The simpler you can make your example, the better.

Comment: Why are you calling `wait_for` at all? There doesn't seem to be anything that you need to wait for. What does the mutex protect? What is the shared state between the two threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the wait_for blocks even after the 1 sec?

How do you know that the main thread ever makes it to the `cv.wait_for(...)` call?

It's not 100% clear what you are asking, but if the program never prints "failed," and you are asking why not, then probably what happened is, the child thread locked the mutex first and then it "slept forever" while keeping the mutex locked. If that happened, then the main thread would never be able to get past the `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mut);` line.

> Is the mut necessary for the thread th ?

That depends. You certainly don't need to lock a mutex in a thread that does nothing but "// sleep forever," but maybe the thread that you are asking about is not exactly the same as what you showed.  Maybe you are asking how wait() and notify() are *supposed* to be used.

I can't give a C++-specific answer, but in *most* programming languages and libraries, wait() and notify() are low-level primitives that are meant to be used in a very specific way:

A "consumer" thread waits by doing something like this:

```
mutex.lock();
while ( ! SomeImportantCondition() ) {
    cond_var.wait(mutex);
}
DoSomethingThatRequiresTheConditionToBeTrue();
mutex.unlock()
```

The purpose of the mutex is to protect the shared data that `SomeImportantCondition()` tests. No other thread should be allowed to change the value that `SomeImportantCondition()` returns while the mutex is locked.

Also, you may already know this, but some readers might not; The reason why `mutex` is given in `cond_var.wait(mutex)` is because the wait function temporarily unlocks the mutex while it is waiting, and then it re-locks the mutex before it returns. The unlock is necessary so that a producer thread will be allowed to make the condition become true. Re-locking is needed to guarantee that the condition still will be true when the consumer accesses the shared data.

The third thing to note is that the consumer *does not wait()* if the condition already is true. A common newbie mistake is to unconditionally call `cv.wait()` and expect that a `cv.notify()` call in some other thread will wake it up. But a `notify()` will *not* wake the consumer thread if it happens *before* the consumer starts waiting.

---

Writing the "producer" is easier. There's no *technical* reason why a "producer" can't just call `cond_var.notify()` without doing anything else at all. But that's not very useful.  Most producers do something like this:

```
mutex.lock();
... Do something that makes SomeImportantCondition() return true;
cond_var.notify();
mutex.unlock();
```

The only really important thing is that the producer locks the mutex before it touches the shared data that are tested by `SomeImportantCondition()`. *Some* programming languages will let you move the `notify()` call after the `unlock()` call. Others won't. It doesn't really matter either way.